# VB.NET Wait a DOS shell program to terminate before continuing- doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, shell, process

I am building a Windows Forms Application on VS2010, through which I need to execute a 3d party DOS shell program (OpenSees.exe), open a source file in it and perform an analysis. After this, some output files are created which I need to read again in my VB.NET app.
The thing is that the analysis in OpenSees may take a long time, so the VB code has to wait for it before carrying on.

For this, I have tried both "ShellandWait" sub along with "WaitForSingleObject" function and "process class" option, but neither of then works.
My DOS shell program initializes, but it closes almost immediately, not letting the analysis to complete and the required output to be created.

Here are the code snippets I used:
1st try: ShellandWait

```
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess _
 As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle _
    As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long


Private Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal program_name As String, _
                         Optional ByVal window_style As AppWinStyle = vbNormalFocus, _
                         Optional ByVal max_wait_seconds As Long = 0)
    Dim lngProcessId As Long
    Dim lngProcessHandle As Long
    Dim datStartTime As Date
    Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = &H102
    Const SYNCHRONIZE As Long = &H100000
    Const INFINITE As Long = &HFFFFFFFF

    ' Start the program.
    On Error GoTo ShellError
    lngProcessId = Shell(program_name, window_style)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
    'System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

    SendKeys.Send("source " & filename & ".tcl")
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

    ' Wait for the program to finish.
    ' Get the process handle.
    lngProcessHandle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, lngProcessId)
    If lngProcessHandle <> 0 Then
        datStartTime = Now
        Do
            If WaitForSingleObject(lngProcessHandle, 250) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            'DoEvents()
            If max_wait_seconds > 0 Then
                If DateDiff("s", datStartTime, Now) > max_wait_seconds Then Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        CloseHandle(lngProcessHandle)
    End If
    Exit Sub

  ShellError:
  End Sub
  ...
  ShellAndWait("OpenSees.exe", , 3)
```

2nd try: ProcessStart

```
Dim p As New Process
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("OpenSees.exe", "source " & filename & ".tcl")
p.StartInfo = psi
p.Start()

p.WaitForExit()
```

I don't understand why this isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is indeed quite unlikely to work correctly.  Passing the *full* path name for both the opensees.exe file *and* the .tcl file is very important.  A full path name is c:\foo\bar\baz.tcl, as opposed to baz.tcl

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the direct reply. I don't think that's the problem (btw I tried full path names as well, but same thing happens). Before trying the above code snippets, I just made use of the Shell command to execute OpenSees & SendKeys commands to open the required file & threading.Thread.Sleep for the VB code to wait. It worked, but it's definitely not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Shell("OpenSees.exe <arguments>",, True)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!